# Node.js server + SSL = ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: node.js, ssl

I've got an node.js app which was running perfectly on http.
Then I added self-signed cert to buildup and test ssl connection.
When it worked out (with chrome notify that somebody could steal something) I bought the ssl cert from local certifier.

When I put the new cert server starts up normally but the browser says:
Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Now what could be the reason?

```
 https          = require('https'),
 fs             = require('fs');
var keys_dir = "./ssl/"
var sslOptions = {
    key   : fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'server.key'), 
    cert : fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'certificate.crt'),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'nazwa1.crt'), fs.readFileSync(keys_dir +'nazwa2.crt')]
};
https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){ *** });
```

the port is 443.
Key is RSA PRIVATE KEY. Cert is based on it.

Node -v v0.10.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I fixed it:
I did check md5 of key and cert and they were different. So i recreated cert and all went nice and smooth.

Comment: I cannot help you now with certain funcs, cause of beeing far away from comp. But, try tu check key md5 sum at key file and at your cert. If you'll google for this youll find answers :-)

Comment: I was able to fix this issue the same way as you.  CSR and key had equal md5 but not X.crt.  But X.chained.crt did.  Turned out the previous dev had been using the wrong cert in the code, and when I renamed the chained file to just  X.crt instead of X.chained.crt it worked again.